# How can I access inputfields in TYPO3-6.2-backend to fill them with javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

If you use the extension-builder there is no option to generate a button. How can you achieve to create a submit-button?
The function of the clicked button should be to read some filled inputfields and execute a javascript function with the input.
The result of this query should fill other empty input fields. The problem here for me is to identify the inputfields by id or name,
that i can fill them with the result of my query.

How can I acchieve that I can fill some backend inputfields with javascript variables by button click? I use TYPO3 version 6.2. How can I generate a simple submit button for this function?

Comment: This seems to be a XY problem. What is your *real* goal? Prefill the fields?

Comment: Please describe what exactly do you wanna achieve. The more details you provide the better answers your gonna get.